# PAR::Packer trouble with included files

Tags: perl, par

I am pretty new to PAR::Packer and I have written a script in Perl.

The problem I am having is when I compile it to .exe and include two files (so it's portable) the EXE file errors out with "cannot open file, no such file or directory"

I can easily make the script into an .exe file and use it as long as the `C:\temp` directory is there. But I want it to use the files that were included in the .exe and not the `C:\temp` directory.

Here is the part of the script in question:

```
open($patch1, '<', "C:/temp/patch1.bin") or die "cannot open this file: $!";
binmode($patch1);
open($patch2, '<', "C:/temp/patch2.bin") or die "cannot open this file: $!";
binmode($patch2);
```

And like I say, all I want it to do is use the files that were included into the .exe and *not* the files from the `C:/temp` directory.

I reckon it could be how I've coded it, but I've tried `"./patch1.bin"` instead of `"C:/temp/patch1.bin"`

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: also i should add all this script does, is open a file, seek to certain offsets, then it writes $patch1 and then seeks to a different offset and writes $patch2. its just a simple seek and write script.

Comment: Anyway, short answer: see http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PAR::Tutorial#Accessing_packed_files

Comment: im apologize if i have duplicated a question. but this is a very very basic script and perl2exe will compile and include the files and it will execute the script and use the files from within the exe. i am trying to accomplish the exact same thing so i can make this portable for any windows pc. but the problem is i do not want to use perl2exe as the .exe's made with it have a 2 sec delay upon exiting the cmd window. i am trying to do away with this 2 sec delay pretty much.

Comment: also, any help explaining this would be very useful. i am not an expirenced programmer by any means and any clarification is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please include a complete script that exhibits your problem (trimmed down to the bare minimum to reproduce the problem).

Answer (score 1):

The code in your question tries to open two files, named `patch1.bin` and `patch2.bin`, from the directory `C:/temp`.  If those files are not present in that directory, the open will fail.

In the comments, you claim that [perl2exe](http://www.indigostar.com/perl2exe.php) will somehow make those files appear in that particular directory if they've been bundled with our program.  I rather doubt that.  According to the [perl2exe user manual](http://www.indigostar.com/pxman.html), bundled files will be extracted into a directory whose name is given by:

```
$temp_dir = ( $ENV{TEMP} || $ENV{TMP} || $ENV{WINDIR} || '/tmp' ) . "/p2xtmp-$$";
```

Depending on your OS and settings, this *might* be a *subdirectory* of `C:/temp`, but it *cannot* be the directory `C:/temp` itself (since it must always contain `p2xtmp` somewhere in the path).  Indeed, if perl2exe *did* extract its bundled files directly into `C:/temp`, or into any other fixed directory, that would be a recipe for disaster if two programs compiled using perl2exe were ever running at the same time and had bundled files with the same name.

Anyway, as the [page I linked to](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PAR%3a%3aTutorial#Accessing_packed_files) suggests, the recommended way to access bundled files under PAR is using `PAR::read_file()`.  For example, if you had a file name `patch1.bin` included in your PAR bundle using [`pp -a`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?pp#a), you could read its contents using:

```
my $contents = PAR::read_file('patch1.bin');
```

If you need more advanced access to bundled files, you can obtain an [Archive::Zip](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Archive%3a%3aZip) object pointing to the entire PAR file using:

```
my $zip = PAR::par_handle($0);
```

and then use that to access the archive members directly.

Comment: thanks, and you are right. now that i remember... i had made an installer for this tool and it was portable. it would build the directory "c:\temp" and would add the patch files there. that is what i did last time to get around this same problem. i will have to try to understand this more lol. thank you very much for the help :)